# Failed to run dexer: Appcelerator Android build_ Titanium SDK: 7.0.1

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I am getting "Failed to run dexer:" while trying to build for Android using Appcelerator.

Appc Studio 5.0.0, Titanium SDK: 7.0.1

Error is as given below:

> 

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnimatorRes;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnyRes;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/ArrayRes;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AttrRes;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/BinderThread;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/BoolRes;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/CallSuper;
[ERROR] :  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/CheckResult;
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[ERROR] :  java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:615)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:368)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:289)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:247)
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:94)
[ERROR] :  Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
[ERROR] :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:607)
[ERROR] :   ... 4 more
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Not sure how we can enable Multi dex in appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can only cross-check which modules are using same set of libraries with different versions & then use a single version of library for all conflicting modules.

e.g. If you use `ti.map` & `firebase.core`, then you can use `ti.playservices` for both modules.

But in your case, the conflicting libraries are from Annotation lib, then you can either provide a list of all your modules here so we can check which one is causing this issue, or you can check yourself for conflicting modules & follow above process to resolve them.